# Custom Plugins in Resharper

Tags: resharper, customization, rule

I ve been trying this for sometime now but unable to get any luck in figuring out how to write custom plugins for a few rules that currently do not exist in R#. At most I want to know whether it's if at all possible to write custom plugins for the below rules. On some sites I've read that it's merely impossible to write plugins for few rules. I just want to give it a try once:

- **Avoid Untyped Dataset** (The strongly typed DataSet provides access to values as the correct type at compile time. With a strongly typed DataSet, type mismatch errors are caught when the code is compiled rather than at run time.)
- **Avoid call to AcceptChanges in a loop** (it is better to call AcceptChanges only once at the end of a loop rather than at each iteration.)
- **Avoid doing select on Datatable in loop** (Calling the Select method on a DataTable in a loop generally involve performance problems because the data is not indexed. It's better to use indexed access methods.)
- **All .net UI controls should follow Hungarian notation** (Eg: lbl for Label, cbo for Checkbox, btn for Button etc Eg: lblMyName)

If at all by any chance it is possible to write the plugins, can anyone help me with a source on how to get started on these specific rules only.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!
Ashish

Answer (score 1):

regarding your mentioned points

- Avoid untyped dataset I guess you need to search for type usages and, if untyped, provide an inspection saying it's not recommended.
- At a particular point in code you can detect if you're in a loop, and if that's the case, complain. Nothing particularly difficult if we're talking same scope.
- Same ideas as above
- This would require a custom inspection. ReSharper already supports naming conventions, but these special prefixes would need to be analyzed separately.

I recommend you consult the [ReSharper Plugin Development Guide](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/ReSharper/ReSharper+8+Plugin+Development), which should get you started on writing R# plugins.